# drag-drop, resize images and then drawing features in 1 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am working on an application where the user comes and sees a blank area(div or canvas or whatever, lets call it mycanvas hereafter). Now he drags some images from outside(a div) and drops them on mycanvas. He can also resize them. And, he can also draw something in mycanvas with pencils and colors with erasing feature. Now, as per my research till now, I've figured out that the drawing part is a pure HTML 5 canvas stuff. So, no problem with that. But I'm not sure whether he can drop images from an outside div/canvas to mycanvas. Please tell me how to achieve all the three features(drag-drop from outside, draw with pencil, resize images) in a single area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve all the required features using kinetic js.

To drag, drop and resize

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

To paint using different shapes, say a line:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-line-tutorial/

and dropping from outside canvas is the simplest thing, probably:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Just check these and let me know if there is any problem in integration.

Comment: i have same situation can you help me out with that i posted one question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582375/drag-and-drop-images-into-canvas

Answer (score 2):

I have create a online dnd editor by Html5Canvas.

I will create  a loop first

```
var loop = function(){
  // Operation Here
}

self.setInterval(loop, 1000/60);
```

Create the data model, for example a image

```
var DndImage = function(x, y, width, height, image){
  this.type = "image";
  this.image = image;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}
```

Then we draw the image in the looping

```
var ObjectArray = new Array();
var WIDTH = 800;
var HEIGHT = 600;
var loop = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  for(var x = 0; x < ObjectArray.length; x++){
    if(ObjectArray[x].type == "image")
      context.drawImage(ObjectArray[x].image,ObjectArray[x].x,ObjectArray[x].y, ObjectArray[x].width, ObjectArray[x].height);
  }
}
```

Function to add New image object

```
function addImage(src, x, y, width, height){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function(){
   ObjectArray.push(new DndImage(x, y, width, height, img)); 
  }
}
```

And now if you want to do a dnd, You need to do is set up a Listener to listen the mouse move event. And set the DndImage Object x and y to follow the mouse position in the image canavs. You can scale the image or changing the size too.

```
docuemnt.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){  });
docuemnt.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){  });
docuemnt.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){  });
docuemnt.addEventListener("click", function(){  });
```

Hope I can help you :D